# Use Google Document's paragraph header style to set the Drive filename

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I am new to the world of Google App Scripting. I am currently working on laying out a literary journal in inDesign. In order to make turning the editors roughdraft from a single gDoc to multiple files easily placeable in indesign i am working on a script that:

1. goes through a gDoc and finds page breaks
2. creates a new document in a folder after the page break
3. names the document based on header styles. header 1 for title, header 2 for author

I have successfully accomplished 1 & 2 but I am stuck on 3. My code is adapted from a preexisting code but i decided to be more fancy and now im so irritated. This is how my testing document looks:
[image: testingDoc]

here is my code:

```
function getFolderName(){
    var response = DocumentApp.getUi().prompt("Enter a folder name");
    if (response.getSelectedButton() == DocumentApp.getUi().Button.OK)
        return DriveApp.createFolder(response.getResponseText());
    return null;
}
function nameSplitSave() {
  var folder = getFolderName();
  if (folder == null)
    return false;

  var pBrk  = DocumentApp.ElementType.PAGE_BREAK;
  var drive = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var par = body.getParagraphs();

  var entry = 1, title = 0, artist = 0;
  var page = DocumentApp.create("Entry" + title + artist);

  for (var i = 0; i < par.length; i++){
    var hasbreak = false;
    var head1 = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1;
    var head2 = DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2;
    var curPar = par[i];
    Logger.log('curPar '+ curPar);
    Logger.log('curPar heading style is '+ curPar.getHeading() + 'heading1' + head1 + 'heading2' + head2);
    if (curPar.getHeading() == head1)
      title = curPar;
    else if (curPar.getHeading() == head2)
      artist = curPar;
    else {
      title ='orange';
      artist ='fart';
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < par[i].getNumChildren(); j++) {
      var child = par[i].getChild(j);
      if (child.getType() == pBrk) {
        hasbreak = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!hasbreak) {
      var seppar = par[i].copy();
      page.getBody().appendParagraph(seppar);
    } else {
      var par1 = par[i].copy();
      var par2 = par[1].copy();
      var hitbreak = false;
      for (var i1 = 0; i1 < par1.getNumChildren(); i1++) {
        if (par1.getChild(i1).getType() == pBrk)
          hitbreak = true;

        if (hitbreak)
          par1.removeChild(par1.getChild(i1));
      }

      hitbreak = false;
      for (var i1 = 0; i1 < par2.getNumChildren(); i1++) {
        if (par2.getChild(i1).getType() == pBrk)
          hitbreak = true;

        if (!hitbreak || par2.getChild(i1).getType() == pBrk)
          par2.removeChild(par2.getChild(i1));
      }
      page.getBody().appendParagraph(par1);
      page.saveAndClose();

      //Add file to folder
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById(page.getId());
      folder.addFile(file);
      drive.removeFile(file);

      entry++;
      page = DocumentApp.create("Entry" + title + artist);
      page.getBody().appendParagraph(par2);
    }
  }
  page.saveAndClose();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(page.getId());
  folder.addFile(file);
  drive.removeFile(file);
}
```

when I run the logger test it shows the following message:

```
curPar Paragraph
curPar heading style is Heading 1heading1Heading 1heading2Heading 2
curPar Paragraph
curPar heading style is Heading 2heading1Heading 1heading2Heading 2
curPar Paragraph
curPar heading style is Normalheading1Heading 1heading2Heading 2
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out what i am doing wrong. any help is appreciated!

The main issue is that, when the file saves out, instead of saving as:
**EntryHeadingTest1TitleHeadingTest2Author**
It saves as
**Entry00**

And if there are multiple pages, instead of getting saved with the heading names, they all get saved as
**Entryorangefart**

What i dont understand is in my `if-else if-else` statement, it looks like `curPar` and `head1` being equal is `true` in the logger but the file is still being saved as "Entry00" and "Entryorangefart"

Comment: What's the problem? You get "Heading 1", "Heading 2", and "Normal" as the paragraph stylings. That seems like it is working just fine.

Comment: @tehhowch sorry i forgot to add my main issue, thanks for your comment

Comment: I edited your code a bit to remove the `UI()` and `Doc()` functions, to simplify what you're presenting. Note that your initial assignment to page, `var page = DocumentApp.create("Entry" + title + author);`, outside of the for loop, means that the first document is always `Entry00`.

Comment: thank you so much @tehhowch! your fixes worked beautifully! i dont know how to accept your fixes as the answer tho

Comment: Post the fixes you've made as an answer: identify where you made mistakes in the original code and the corrected method.